# Not able to browse PnP PowerShell documentation on Microsoft site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, provisioning, documentation

I am trying to access PnP PowerShell documentation but not able to find it. Almost all pages are not working.

Example: I am trying to access PnP Provisioning template cmdlet documentation which is giving error 404 not found.

Please suggest new URL.

[Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PnP PowerShell documentation migrated to new URL.

This is new URL: [PnP PowerShell documentation](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/index.html).

You can find the cmdlets under the **Cmdlets** tab.

**Related thread**: [Not able to access PnP PowerShell documentation](https://twitter.com/GaneshSanap20/status/1360187543925395459)

[Reply from PnP PowerShell](https://twitter.com/PnpPowershell/status/1360211304552759299) twitter account:

> We are working on getting the new documentation in place.